# How to initialize a combo box in a form?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

My understanding is that initialization code runs when I invoke "New UserForm2".

Below is the code that invokes a New userform and the code associated with the userform.

I stepped through with the debugger and watched it execute the initialization code, but it has no affect on the form. The combo box is still blank.

```vb
If TabID = "5 Client List" Then
    With New UserForm2
        .Show
        If Not .IsCancelled Then
            If InStr(TarSheet, "5.1") Then
                Call General_Transfer(TabID, TarSheet, 28, "Yes")
            End If
            TarSheet = ""
        End If
    End With
    Exit Sub
End If
```

```vb
' UserForm2 Code
Option Explicit
'@Folder("UI")
Private cancelled As Boolean
 
Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property
 
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TarSheet = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Hide
End Sub
 
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    TarSheet = ""
    OnCancel
End Sub
 
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
    End If 
End Sub
 
Private Sub OnCancel()
    cancelled = True
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    UserForm2.ComboBox1.AddItem "5.1 Client List LTS"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Me` instead of `UserForm2` ?  Your code works for me as posted though...

Comment: This things are truly ... Me works fine.  Thanks for the suggestion.